# How to wake a network drive from batch script?

Tags: windows-7, batch, robocopy, network-drive

I have a batch script which runs a robocopy. It is failing because the drive is not awake.
[image]

In windows explorer, doubling clicking on that icon "wakes" up the link and the cross disappears and the robocopy runs without issue.

How can I wake it up in a batch file?

**Additional Info**: If my PC sleeps or reboots. The batch script does not run until i wake the drive via the icon. The two machines are not on a domain and they use the same username and password (administrator).

**Additional Info 2:**  Note the unavailable drive.

```
Status       Local     Remote                    Network

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
OK           P:        \\fileserver2008\P        Microsoft Windows Network
Unavailable  T:        \\fileserver2008\T        Microsoft Windows Network
```

Comment: +1 because I'm interested in the solution for this for re-connecting drive letters after OpenVPN connections become fully functional.

Comment: I have added additional info

Answer (score 7):

I am not familiar with this problem but you may want to try out two things:

1. Try running a Dir command against the drive and see if it wakes up:
   Dir T:\
2. You can always disconnect and then connect the drive again from the command line, IE: from your batch program.

Comment: +1: Reconnecting has always worked for me.

Comment: The dir command results in `The system cannot find the path specified.`. I know that reconnecting the drive would work. I wish to avoid it as I would like to find something else.

Comment: Solution 1 doesn't work for me either.  Solution 2 is a last resort, but it's not as slick as the automatic re-connect.  +1 for a great effort though.

Comment: This did work up until recently for me but no longer working. Getting the same `cannot find the path specified` message. Also `copy thisfiledoesnawtexist.txt Z:\ ` doesn't work as it used to.

Answer (score 1):

How about pinging it's IP address, does that wake it up? Failing that see if there's some kind of WOL command to cause the disk to initialise...

Comment: This doesn't wake up Windows network drive mappings, unfortunately.  This is because ICMP is an entirely different protocol from SMB.  +1 for a good attempt though.

Comment: +1 for the +1! Tend to always disable drive sleeping as all the network issues it used to cause... Old habits die hard :)